# Apex maps, component unknow, console developer

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I can not use the apex maps module.
error console: unknown module apex maps

i am using console dev from web salesforce and i am "free user" i have not edicion special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer Edition accounts do not get access to apex:map. This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_maps.htm).

> Visualforce mapping components aren’t available in Developer Edition organizations.

Comment: Thank you, I need show whit the class "account" ShippingAddress and BillingAddress, How could I do that? whit dev edition

Comment: @Diego You would need to use an alternative service, like leaflet.js.